# MYSQL calculate amount from two table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 mysql tables:

"Orders" table:

```
customer_id | money
3             120
5             80
3             45
3             70
6             20
```

"collecting" table:

```
customer_id | money
3             50
3             70
4             20
4             90
```

I want a result like:

"Total" table:

```
customer_id | Amount
3             115
4             110
5             80
6             20
```

1. "Total" table "customer_id" should be singular
2. Amount = (SUM(All customer orders.money) - SUM(All customer collecting.money))
3. "Money" can be NULL

"Orders" table can have customer_id and "Collecting" table may not have

Or

"Collecting" table can have customer_id and "Orders" table may not have

How can i write a single query for output "Total" table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way is to union your data with the money value being negative on the `collecting` table:

```
-- load test data
    create table orders(customer_id int, money int);
    insert into orders values
      (3,120),
      (5,80),
      (3,45),
      (3,70),
      (6,20);
    create table collecting(customer_id int,money int);
    insert into collecting values
      (3,50),
      (3,70),
      (4,20),
      (4,90);

-- populate Total table
    create table Total(customer_id int,Amount int);
    insert into Total
      select oc.customer_id,sum(oc.money) Amount
      from (
           select customer_id,coalesce(money,0) money from orders
           union all
           select customer_id,coalesce(-money,0) money from collecting
           ) oc
      group by oc.customer_id;

-- return results   
    select * from Total;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/deebc

Comment: i added "COALESCE(money, 0)" for null values, then i think this query is most short and usefull.

Answer (score 3):

The following returns the result you expect.

```
SELECT 
customer_id,
SUM(amount) as amount
FROM (
  SELECT customer_id, SUM(money) as amount
  FROM orders GROUP BY customer_id

  UNION ALL

  SELECT customer_id, SUM(money) * -1 as amount
  FROM collecting GROUP BY customer_id
) as tb
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

customer_id = 4 returns -110, not 110, since it's only in the collecting table.

Example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b922/5/0

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this by pre-aggregating the data.  If I assume that the `orders` come first, you can use `left outer join`:

```
select o.customer_id, (o.money - coalesce(c.money)) as Amount
from (select o.customer_id, sum(o.money) as money
      from orders o
      group by o.customer_id
     ) o left outer join
     (select c.customer_id, sum(c.money) as money
      from collecting c
      group by c.customer_id
     ) c
     on o.customer_id = c.customer_id;
```

Comment: This query only works if customer is on both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN c.customer_id IS NULL
            THEN o.customer_id
        ELSE c.customer_id
        END
    ,sum(o.MONEY) - sum(c.MONEY)
FROM orders o
OUTER JOIN collecting c ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT customer_id, SUM(o_money - c_money) AS Amount
FROM (
     SELECT customer_id, money AS o_money, 0 AS c_money FROM orders
     UNION ALL
     SELECT customer_id, 0 AS o_money, money AS c_money FROM collecting
     ) total
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

According to your description, you need a `FULL [OUTER] JOIN`, which is a combination of `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`. Many databases don't support `FULL JOIN`, so you need to use `UNION ALL` to reach the same effect.